# Tomcat connection time out when running on port 8443

Tags: ssl, https, connection-timeout, tomcat9

This is a new server. I am trying to get tomcat to run on 8443. I have set up the certs and changed my server.xml file. I am able to get to https on port 8080(I know I am not suppose to use 8080 but was just testing to see if my certs are working). Catalina.out gives no error and 8443 is listening. However, I am getting a connection time out (this site can't be reached. took too long to respond) when I try to go to https://localhost:8443. https://localhost:8080 is working fine.

Is there anything else I need to do?

netstat shows 8443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      117731/java

Comment: browser says resource is online but is not responding to connection attempts, possibly due to firewall or security policy setting. windows couldn't find any problems with the firewall on your computer.

Comment: Tomcat is not running on any other ports. I tried change 8080 to 9090 and http and it is also connection time out.